# How can I filter the result of DynamoDB? (NodeJS / Lambda)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

i'm making an API in AWS Lambda with NodeJS and DynamoDB and'm trying to get details of a specific customer or customers who comes from Colorado (state = Colorado).

Here i was trying to get all customers from Colorado.

```
router.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'Customer',
      FilterExpression: "stateOrProvince = :state",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":state": "Colorado"
      }
    };
    dynamoDb.query(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: `Error fetching the ${tableName}` });
      }
      res.json(result.Items);
    });
});
```

Here i was trying to get details from a specific customer

```
router.get("/customers/:customerId", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.customerId
    const params = {
      TableName: 'Customer',
      FilterExpression: "customerId = :custId",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":custId": id
      }
    };
    dynamoDb.query(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: `Error fetching the ${tableName}` });
      }
      res.json(result.Items);
    });
});
```

Both cases i'm getting a 502 error in postman :|

{
"message": "Internal server error"
}

Could you help me to identify what the issue is ?
I've read and tried differents syntaxes but I couldn't get it to work yet
Thanks

Comment: possible to share your attributes data types and check whether you are passing correct data type ? and also can you check are you using documentClient?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Query` operation without using a `KeyConditionExpression` which you have not defined. You must at least insert the partition key for a `Query`.

Try below, which uses Scan instead:

```
router.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'Customer',
      FilterExpression: "stateOrProvince = :state",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":state": "Colorado"
      }
    };
    dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: `Error fetching the ${tableName}` });
      }
      res.json(result.Items);
    });
});
```

Or for a specific customer, set KeyConditionExpression:

```
router.get("/customers/:customerId", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.customerId
    const params = {
      TableName: 'Customer',
      KeyConditionExpression: "customerId = :custId",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":custId": id
      }
    };
    dynamoDb.query(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: `Error fetching the ${tableName}` });
      }
      res.json(result.Items);
    });
});
```

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression)